# In Python, how can I remove characters around a specific character?

Tags: python, list, strip

I have a list that looks like the following. Within each item of the list, separate items are delimited by a semicolon, but there the amount of space surrounding each semicolon seems to be random:

```
['New Jersey  ;   46.3% ;  Republican ;         03/10/2015', 'Pennsylvania ; 
      39.0%; Democrat    ;04/30/2012', 'Virginia .   ;54.7% ;Independent 
   ;10/25/10',       'Maryland;44.8%   ;        Democrat; 01/15/16', 'New York;  R50.9%; Republican ;                  09/22/15']
```

I would like the final output to be a list that looks like the following:

```
['New Jersey;46.3%;Republican;03/10/2015', 'Pennsylvania;39.0%;Democrat;04/30/2012', 'Virginia;54.7%;Independent;10/25/10' ... ]
```

I've been trying `.split()`, but that's not dropping the characters in the middle. Is doing a `.replace()` on each possible combination of spaces and semicolons my only hope?

Comment: Thank you for the cleaned-up formatting, Vineeth Sai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a short way of doing it. This one line should be enough.

```
s = ['New Jersey  ;   46.3% ;  Republican ;         03/10/2015', 'Pennsylvania ; 39.0%; Democrat    ;04/30/2012', 'Virginia .   ;54.7% ;Independent ;10/25/10',       'Maryland;44.8%   ;        Democrat; 01/15/16', 'New York;  R50.9%; Republican ;                  09/22/15']

new_list = [';'.join([word.strip() for word in item.split(';')]) for item in s]
```

And here's the Expanded Form.

```
new_list = []

for item in s:
    sub_list = [word.strip() for word in item.split(';')]
    new_list.append(';'.join(sub_list))

print(new_list)
```

Outputs:

```
['New Jersey;46.3%;Republican;03/10/2015', 'Pennsylvania;39.0%;Democrat;04/30/2012', 'Virginia .;54.7%;Independent;10/25/10', 'Maryland;44.8%;Democrat;01/15/16', 'New York;R50.9%;Republican;09/22/15']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `replace` function:

```
>>> new_list = [val.replace(' ', '') for val in old_list]
```

Edit:  As pointed out, this removes spaces in words like "New Jersey". Instead, use a regex replace:

```
>>> import re
>>> new_list = [re.sub(' +\.', '', re.sub(' *; *', ';', val)) for val in old_list]
>>> new_list
 ['New Jersey;46.3%;Republican;03/10/2015',
 'Pennsylvania;39.0%;Democrat;04/30/2012',
 'Virginia;54.7%;Independent;10/25/10',
 'Maryland;44.8%;Democrat;01/15/16',
 'New York;R50.9%;Republican;09/22/15']
```

Comment: This will unfortunately also get rid of the space between "New" and "Jersey" in "New Jersey"

Answer (score 1):

```
old_list = ['New Jersey  ;   46.3% ;  Republican ;         03/10/2015', 'Pennsylvania ; 
  39.0%; Democrat    ;04/30/2012', 'Virginia .   ;54.7% ;Independent 
  ;10/25/10',       'Maryland;44.8%   ;        Democrat; 01/15/16', 'New York;    R50.9%; Republican ;                  09/22/15'] 


for row in old_list:
     data = [words.strip() for words in row.split(";")]
     old_list[old_list.index(row)] = ";".join(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Combined use of re.sub() and replace():

```
re.sub(r"\s*([;,])\s*",r"\1",txt).replace(",",", ")
```